# How to change color/borderColor of concrete country in react-leaflet

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I have a map with marker on London. How can i change Great Britain color/borders?

```
<MapContainer 
    center={[51.505, -0.09]}
    zoom={5}
    scrollWheelZoom={true}
    style={{width:"100%", height:"100%"}}
    fullscreenControl={true}
    
>
    <TileLayer
        attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        url={`https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`}
    />
    
    <Marker position={[51.505, -0.09]}/>

</MapContainer>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need a geojson that shows only the country you want and not the whole world countries. You can find a GBR geojson [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/inmagik/world-countries/master/countries/GBR.geojson).

Now to change the border color, this can be easily achieved by defining `fillColor` as `transparent` and specifying the `color` you want on the style prop of `GeoJSON` component.

```
function style(feature) {
    return {
      fillColor: "transparent",
      weight: 2,
      opacity: 1,
      color: "red", //Outline color
      fillOpacity: 1
    };
  }

{geoJSON && <GeoJSON data={geoJSON} style={style} />}
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-change-colorbordercolor-of-concrete-country-in-react-leaflet-v3x-9dcbn?file=/src/App.js:1231-1284)